# Does an LDAP query exist to list mailbox databases from an exchange server?

Tags: database, ldap, exchange-server

I'm building a mini web portal to create user accounts. I have an LDAP query to list each available Exchange server. Now I need a query to list all available databases on each server.

Is this possible with LDAP & Exchange 2013?

Comment: Please post your ldap query to list all available exchange server...